# Preventing Cross site scripting for checkboxes

Tags: jstl

We have a Cross site scripting vulnerablity in our code and we suspect the below code is the one reponsible

And we have been suggested to use `<c:out>` tag to prevent

My question is, will `<c:out>` defenitely prevent cross site?

if so what will be `<c:out>` implemnetation of the below code

or please suggest a optimal solution, thanks a lot

```
<td class="label">Test ID:</td>
<td class="userData"><form:checkbox path="subject1.testId"/></td>
```

Comment: What makes you think these two lines constitute a XSS vulnerability? By which tag would you replace the `form:checkbox` tag to make it safer?

Comment: Our ethical scanning team are saying this checkbox is not output encoded and hence it is vulnerable ... this is all the info i got till now.

Answer (score 0):

No amount of editing your HTML will protect you from cross-site-scripting. If the client can see it, the client can copy it.

You need to validate your inputs better.